# toggle div content when click anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have simple slider which I open/close on click event.

```
$('#tab1-slideout span').click(function () {
    manageToggleStateTab1();
});

function manageToggleStateTab1() {
   if (tab1ToggleState == 'collapsed') {
      $('#tab1-content').slideToggle('slow');
      $('#tab1-slideout span').addClass('active');
      tab1ToggleState = 'expanded';
});
```

and on page load I set this tab1ToggleState with initial value

```
var tab1ToggleState  = 'collapsed';
```

this works great but I want to expand this further in order to allow toggling state on click event anywhere outside `#tab1-content` container div.

I tried to wire click event anywhere on page except the one with toggle content

```
 $(document).not($('#tab1-content')).click(function () {     
    manageToggleStateTab1();
 });
```

but this not gives me desired result, div immediately slide down after it slide up.

Comment: And you did of course remove the old event handler, so you don't have two event handlers both toggling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this function

```
// hide some divs when click on window
function actionwindowclick(e , el , action){
    if (!$(el).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && $(el).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            action();
        }
  }
```

in click event

```
$(document).click(function (e) {     
    actionwindowclick(e , '#tab1-content' , function(){
       // do action here
    });
 });
```

simply this function says  if the element is not a target do the action

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/3k9j8agL/)

and while you use `$(document).click(...` you will need [**event.stopPropagation()**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

so for example

```
$('#tab1-slideout span').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    manageToggleStateTab1();
});
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/3k9j8agL/1/)